# Pushing functions into an Array in Javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays

Is there a way to push a list of functions into an associative array? Here's what I'm trying to do:

```
var inits = {
    "first"  : fn1(),
    "second" : fn2(),
    "third"  : fn3(),
    "fourth" : fn4()

};

var functions = ['first','fourth'];

for(var index in functions ) {

    inits[functions[index]];

}
```

The important part here is to be able to name each function and have it called based on a given array of function names. I can do this in PHP but can't figure it out how to do it in javascript.

Comment: Keep in mind that an associative array is actually just an object in Javascript.

Comment: @Mr.Alien Why would you say that?

Comment: @KodleeYin I realized I was missing the invoking part...

Comment: @Dimitri As pointed out in a comment in one of the answers, make sure when the "associative array" is defined, that the values of the elements are function definitions and not function calls!

Comment: @alexn I would chain the functions instead of storing them in an object

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, you're not actually storing functions. You're storing the *return* value of functions.

To store the function, you'd use

```
var inits = {
  'first': fn1,
  'second': fn2,
   ...
};
```

Secondly, you're iterating incorrectly over the array.

Use `forEach`:

```
functions = ['first', 'fourth'];

functions.forEach(function (fn) {
    inits[fn];
});
```

Thirdly, in your loop, you don't actually try to *invoke* the function. If that's your intent, you're missing a `()`:

```
functions.forEach(function (fn) {
    inits[fn]();
});
```

Comment: @Dimitri It's not, though you could just as easily store the functions directly: `functions [fn1, fn2]`. The person who told you this is "absurd" had no business doing so, there is too little context for him to have drawn such a conclusion.

Answer (score 1):

Just a few small changes should make it work:

```
var inits = {
    "first"  : function() { /* make sure there's a function body */ },

    "second" : fn2,   // or this, if you intend to call a function named `fn2`
                      // or assigned to a locally accessible fn2 variable.

    "third"  : fn3(), // or this, if fn3() returns a function ...
    "fourth" : fn4(), // but, this version *probably* isn't what you want.

};

var functions = ['first','fourth'];

// generally speaking, don't use for-in on an array.
for(var i = 0; i < functions.length; i++) {

    // use parentheses to invoke the function
    inits[functions[i]]();

}
```

Comment: That will only work if fn1, fn2 etc. returns functions.

Comment: You probably mean `function() { .. }` instead of `fn1() { .. }`.

Comment: @alexn Doesn't look like there *is* a downvoter ... Just someone rapidly up-voting and un-voting ...

Comment: @svidgen Thank you, just a major oversight on my part; this makes perfect sense! Why would something like this be considered bad programming?

Comment: @Dimitri Not sure. I think we're missing too much context to say what you're doing is categorically absurd or bad ...